# CodeName one Google Maps. Waited too long for browser bridge

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

Previously Google Maps works fine on my Android device. I did not change any code and certificates. Now I am getting the following error Log:

```
EDT] 0:20:38,90 - Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException - Waited too long for browser bridge
java.lang.RuntimeException: Waited too long for browser bridge
    at com.codename1.g.d$a.a(MapContainer.java:262)
    at com.codename1.g.d$a.b(MapContainer.java:223)
    at com.codename1.g.d.a(MapContainer.java:709)
    at com.zetta.survey.a.c.a(GoogleMapsTestApp.java:78)
    at com.zetta.survey.d$2.a(MainMenu.java:144)
    at com.codename1.s.r.a(Form.java:1621)
    at com.codename1.s.ae$a$a.run(SideMenuBar.java:1745)
    at com.codename1.s.n.l(Display.java:1101)
    at com.codename1.s.n.j(Display.java:1045)
    at com.codename1.s.n.i(Display.java:946)
    at com.codename1.s.ad.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: That's usually associated with a network latency. Try running your app on a different network.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Tried with different network also.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the native maps are failing to initialize so it is falling back to the web-based maps - which shouldn't happen on device.  Things to check:

1. Make sure your app has the android.playService.maps=true build hint.
2. Refresh cn1libs, and clean and build, then try again.

Try reading the device log in DDMS.  There is surely an error reported when it fails to create that native map.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I had done this. But failed again. What is the correct constructor for MapContainer to display the Google map in android device? a) final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer(); or b) final MapContainer cnt = new MapContainer(HTML_KEY);   a or b?

Comment: Both are fine.  The parameter only makes a difference on the browser.  So when you hooked up the device to DDMS what did the error say?